# Insert element between self-closing elements

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

In an XML document, I intend to insert elements between two self-closing elements. Consider the following example:

```
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    <lb/>consectetur adipisici elit,
    <lb/>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt
    <lb/>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    <lb/>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    <lb/>laboris nisi ut aliquid
    <lb/>ex ea commodi consequat.
  </p>
</body>
```

So there are structures like paragraphs (p) and line breaks (lb). My aim is now to put the lines into elements. So I would like to achieve the following transformation result (or similar):

```
<body>
  <p>
    <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</l>
    <l>consectetur adipisici elit,</l>
    <l>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt</l>
    <l>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
  </p>
  <p>
    <l>Ut enim ad minim veniam,</l>
    <l>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</l>
    <l>laboris nisi ut aliquid</l>
    <l>ex ea commodi consequat.</l>
  </p>
</body>
```

Is this actually possible with XSLT? It seems that this is not a typical application, as I have not found an approach yet. I would be grateful for any help.

EDIT:
Here comes a more complex variant of the problem, which adds:
(1) highlighted, overlapping passages (hi) and
(2) an overlapping "choice" element, of which only the "sic" element needs to be preserved.

```
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    <lb/>consectetur adipisici elit,
    <lb/>sed eiusmod tempor <hi>incidunt
    <lb/>ut labore</hi> et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim <choice>
      <sic>venima, <lb/>quis noster</sic>
      <corr>veniam, quis nostrud</corr>
    </choice> exercitation ullamco
    <lb/>laboris nisi ut aliquid
    <lb/>ex ea commodi consequat.
  </p>
</body>
```

Desired output would be, for example, with
(1) line numbers, and
(2) a @cont attribute, which indicates continuation of a splitted element.

```
<body>
  <p>
    <l n="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</l>
    <l n="2">consectetur adipisici elit,</l>
    <l n="3">sed eiusmod tempor <hi cont="true">incidunt</hi></l>
    <l n="4"><hi cont="false">ut labore</hi> et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
  </p>
  <p>
    <l n="5">Ut enim ad minim <sic cont="true">venima,</sic></l>
    <l n="6"><sic cont="false">quis noster</sic> exercitation ullamco</l>
    <l n="7">laboris nisi ut aliquid</l>
    <l n="8">ex ea commodi consequat.</l>
  </p>
</body>
```

This practically covers the worst cases I encountered. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime? In that case it is a job for `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="lb"><l><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/text()/normalize-space()"/></l></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Yes, I am using Oxygen, so there are some options concerning XSLT processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is always an `lb` element between lines, the following will do, because text content that is separated by child elements ends up in separate text nodes.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                <l>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </l>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <p>
      <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</l>
      <l>consectetur adipisici elit,</l>
      <l>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt</l>
      <l>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
   </p>
   <p>
      <l>Ut enim ad minim veniam,</l>
      <l>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</l>
      <l>laboris nisi ut aliquid</l>
      <l>ex ea commodi consequat.</l>
   </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Good! This is pointing me to the right direction. Actually my example is very simplified, so maybe I will add another example later.

Comment: @friedemann_bach For your future questions, please make sure the input XML you show accurately reflects the level of complexity present in your actual data. Otherwise, we are bound to give an answer that is not helpful.

Comment: @friedemann_bach So, how do we go on with your question? Please edit your question to include an extended sample of your input XML as you have suggested yourself.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I posted the simplified example first just to understand whether there was actually an easy solution to my basic problem. Posting the more complex example now.

Answer (score 3):

> Here comes a more complex variant of the problem, which adds: (1)
>   highlighted, overlapping passages (hi) and (2) an overlapping "choice"
>   element, of which only the "sic" element needs to be preserved.

Well, that's interesting - although it may be way too much for a single SO question. In any case, I couldn't find a way to do all of that at once. The following stylesheet uses two passes to return a result that is *almost* what you requested:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="first-pass">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="first-pass"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- FIRST-PASS TEMPLATES -->

<!-- remove choice wrapper, preserve only sic content  -->
<xsl:template match="choice" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sic" mode="first-pass"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- split hi and sic accross lb -->
<xsl:template match="hi | sic" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:variable name="elem-name" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="text()" group-by="generate-id(preceding-sibling::lb[1])">
        <xsl:element name="{$elem-name}">
        <xsl:attribute name="cont" select="position()!=last()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="first-pass"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <lb/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<!-- OUTPUT -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- create a line element for each group separated by lb -->
<xsl:template match="*[lb]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="lb">
            <l n="{position()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </l>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress lb -->
<xsl:template match="lb"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <p>
      <l n="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </l>
      <l n="2">consectetur adipisici elit,
    </l>
      <l n="3">sed eiusmod tempor <hi cont="true">incidunt
    </hi>
      </l>
      <l n="4">
         <hi cont="false">ut labore</hi> et dolore magna aliqua.
  </l>
   </p>
   <p>
      <l n="1">Ut enim ad minim <sic cont="true">venima, </sic>
      </l>
      <l n="2">
         <sic cont="false">quis noster</sic> exercitation ullamco
    </l>
      <l n="3">laboris nisi ut aliquid
    </l>
      <l n="4">ex ea commodi consequat.
  </l>
   </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Great, many thanks. This works better than I expected. Nonetheless, I gave the "answer" check to @mathias-müller because he answered my initial question perfectly. Maybe I have to split up such issues in two questions next time.

Comment: If during the first pass you add a <lb/> at the end of each p, you can then have the correct line count using {count(current-group()[last()]/preceding::lb) + 1} instad of {position()}